# how to automate execution of colab notebook using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, google-colaboratory

**my code is:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://colab.research.google.com/drive/any colab link=sharing"

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

first_run_botton = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value = r'div > div.cell-execution-indicator > iron-icon')[0]

print(first_run_botton)

first_run_botton.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

```
error is Exception has occurred: IndexError
list index out of range
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python projects\python yt_video auto\automate colab.py", line 14, in <module>
    first_run_botton = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value = r'div > div.cell-execution-indicator > iron-icon')[0]
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

all run botton have same css selector and xpath, css selector and xpath is copied from chrome
please help!!

Comment: Link is not valid or inaccessible getting error `page not Found - Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.`

Comment: you can use any colab link to text i only want to run the first cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to click on the Run cell button for snippets, if you look at colab html you can cleary see that its part of a shadow DOM that why you are not able to access it directly in Selenium. if there is any element which comes under `#shadow-root(open)` we need to first find the parent of that and then get the shadowroot and then you can access the elements inside shadowroot

[image]

Below solution should work i have tested them on sample colab link below

#1 If you are using Selenium > 4.1 , you can access shadowRoot thorugh sleenium itself as it has support for it from version > 4.1, This should click on Run button for first snippet , you can update locators as per your link

```
driver.get("https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb")

driver.implicitly_wait(20)
# Find Shadow Element First
shadow = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//colab-run-button[@aria-label="Run cell"])[2]').shadow_root

runButton = shadow.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="cell-execution-indicator"] > iron-icon')
runButton.click()
```

If you using selenium 3. version then we need use javascript to first get the shadowroot and then traverse through it to get the run button

```
driver.get("https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb")

driver.implicitly_wait(20)

# Find Shadow Element First
shadow = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//colab-run-button[@aria-label="Run cell"])[2]')

shadow = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot;', shadow)

runButton = shadow.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="cell-execution-indicator"] > iron-icon')
runButton.click()
```

Read this to understand more about [Shadow DOM](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/shadow-dom-in-selenium/)